# Efficiently matching a set of filenames with regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using Perl to capture the names of files in some specified folders that have certain words in them. The keywords in those filenames are "offers" or "cleared" and "regup" or "regdn". In other words, one of "offers" or "cleared" AND one of "regup" or "regdn" must appear in the filename to be a positive match. The two words could be in any order and there are characters/words that will appear in front of and behind them. A sample matching filename is:

```
2day_Agg_AS_Offers_REGDN-09-JUN-11.csv
```

I have a regex that successfully captures each of the matching filenames as a full path, which is what I wanted, but it seems inelegant and inefficient. Attempts at slightly better code have all failed.

Working approach:

```
# Get the folder names
my @folders = grep /^\d{2}-/, readdir DIR;

foreach my $folder ( @folders ) {
    # glob the contents of the folder (to get the file names)
    my @contents = <$folder/*>;

    # For each filename in the list, if it matches, print it
    foreach my $item ( @contents ) {
        if ($item =~ /^$folder(?=.*(offers|cleared))(?=.*(regup|regdn)).*csv$/i){
            print "$item\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Attempt at something shorter/cleaner:

```
foreach my $folder ( @folders ) {
    # glob the contents of the folder (to get the file names)
    my @contents = <$folder/*>;

    # Seems to determine that there are four matches in each folder
    # but then prints the first matching filename four times
    my $single = join("\n", @contents);
    for ($single =~ /^$folder(?=.*(offers|cleared))(?=.*(regup|regdn)).*csv$/im) {
        print "$&\n";#"Matched: |$`<$&>$'|\n\n";
    }
}
```

I've tried other formatting with the regex, using other options (/img, /ig, etc.), and sending  the output of the regex to an array, but nothing has worked properly. I'm not great with Perl, so I'm positive I'm missing some big opportunities to make this whole procedure more efficient. Thanks!

Comment: Is the first set of words always happening before the second set?

Comment: Not necessarily. A word from (offers|cleared) could appear before or after (regup|regdn).

Comment: Why would it be shorter or cleaner to use `join` instead of a loop? I'd say it makes it more complicated.

Comment: It's not necessarily. It could be worse. I put in that code to show an example of one of the things that I tried doing. Fundamentally, I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to do what I've got working using nested for loops and an if statement by better leveraging what can be done with a regex (or something else altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would it be shorter or cleaner to use join instead of a loop? I'd say it makes it more complicated. What you seem to be doing is just matching loosely based on the conditions

- name contains `offers` or `cleared`
- name contains `regup` or  `regdn`
- name ends with `.csv`.

So why not just do this:

```
if ( $file =~ /offers|cleared/i and
     $file =~ /regup|regdn/i    and
     $file =~ /csv$/i)
```

You might be interested in something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my $dir = "/some/dir";
my @files;
find(sub { /offers|cleared/i && 
           /regup|regdn/i &&
           /csv$/i && push @files, $File::Find::name }, $dir);
```

Which would completely exclude the use of readdir and other loops. `File::Find` is recursive.

Comment: I've never used the File::Find module before, but relying on its inbuilt recursive property is pretty slick. This works quite nicely.

Comment: It is a very nice module, and also a core module in Perl 5.

Answer (score 1):

Collect only these file names which contain `offers` or `cleared` AND `regup` or `regdn`

```
my @contents = grep { /offers|cleared/i && /regup|regdn/i } <$folder/*>;
```

Comment: Just to clarify, I actually have to go one deeper in the file tree, so the grep actually pulls the folders that match where I want to look (the folders have dates formatted as MM-DD-YYYY, hence the \d{2}-). I then look in each of those folders with the first foreach loop, hence the glob line just inside that loop.